# Залить проект на bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

почему не заливает?

```
D:\Laravel\projects\rusodev.ru>git remote add origin https://aslero@bitbucket.org/aslero/florida.git
fatal: remote origin already exists.

D:\Laravel\projects\rusodev.ru>git push -u origin --all
To https://bitbucket.org/aslero/florida
 ! [rejected]          master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://aslero@bitbucket.org/aslero/florida'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: вам же пишет - надо сделать pull ! Если же там типа пустой репозиторий то надо добавить к push --force

Comment: @binliz если пустой, то достаточно push -u origin. Видимо там уже что-то есть, либо делать pull, а потом push, либо делать push --force, но тогда затруться данные, которые там уже есть

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084169/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-git-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f